# Modify values in xml

Tags: c#

I have an xml file in following format :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.2">
  <extensions>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan" />
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.cmp" />
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3" />
  </extensions>
    <appSettings>
      <property name="EXTERNAL_FILESERVER" value="/site/bugbase.adobe.com/files/" />
      <property name="FTP_USER" value="password" />
      <property name="FTP_SERVER" value="sjshare.corp.adobe.com"/>
      <property name="FTP_PASSWORD" value="password" />
      <property name="FTP_READ_USER" value="password" />
      <property name="FTP_READ_PASS" value="password" />
      <property name="WORKFLOW_NOTIFICATION_TEMPLATE" value="util/workflow_notification_template.html"/>
    </appSettings>
</server>
```

I wanted to change password values for "FTP_USER" and "FTP_READ_USER".

Code i tried so far :

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            string path = @"C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\config file 1.xml";
            doc.Load(path);
            doc.SelectNodes("/appSettings/property").Item(1).Attributes["value"].Value = "newpassword";
            doc.SelectNodes("/appSettings/property").Item(2).Attributes["value"].Value = "new_password";
```

Comment: Try `"/appSettings/property[@name='FTP_PASSWORD']/@value"` and so on.

Comment: @Tomalak : Can i have a one liner code for this. Thanks

Comment: No. This was more than enough of a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: You mean this :  doc.SelectNodes("/appSettings/property[@name='FTP_USER'/@value]").Item(1).Attributes["value"].Value = "new password";

Comment: doc.SelectNodes("/appSettings/property[@name='FTP_USER']/@value='new password'");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of doing

```
doc.SelectNodes("/appSettings/property").Item(1).Attributes["value"].Value = "password1";
```

use a `foreach` loop

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
string path = @"C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\config file 1.xml";
doc.Load(path);

foreach (XmlNode selectNode in doc.SelectNodes("/appSettings/property"))
{
    if(selectNode.Attributes["name"].Value.equals("FTP_USER") ||
       selectNode.Attributes["name"].Value.equals("FTP_READ_USER"))
    {
        selectNode.Attributes["value"].Value = "new_password";
    }
}

doc.Save(path);
```

and if need two different passwords

```
    if(selectNode.Attributes["name"].Value.equals("FTP_USER"))
    {
        selectNode.Attributes["value"].Value = "new_password";
    }

    if(selectNode.Attributes["name"].Value.equals("FTP_READ_USER"))
    {
        selectNode.Attributes["value"].Value = "newPassword";
    }
```

Comment: you are incrementing password value, which is absolutely not required.

Comment: @AseemKamaal you've edited your question! i'll edit the answer

Comment: This will change password for which user : "FTP_USER" or "FTP_READ_USER" ? I m confused.

Comment: Yor code is changing password for all the users whereas i nedd to change only for 2 users already mentioned above.

Comment: @AseemKamaal i haven't seen that. here i've edited the answer. sorry about that

Comment: No problem.. One more thing what should be done if there is a need to change different passwords for these two users ? Thanks for solution..

Comment: Gives error message : "Cannot implicitly convert type string to bool"

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to change the passwords

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("C:\\test.xml");
    if (xDoc != null)
    {
        IEnumerable<XElement> xEle = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//property");
        if (xEle != null)
        {
           foreach (XElement xE in xEle)
            {
                if (xE.Attribute("name") != null)
                {
                   if(xE.Attribute("value") !=null)
                    {
                    if(string.compare(xE.Attribute("name").Value,"FTP_USER",true) ==0)
                       xE.Attribute("value").Value = "your new password"
                    if(string.compare(xE.Attribute("name").Value,"FTP_READ_USER",true) ==0)
                       xE.Attribute("value").Value = "your new password"

                     }

                }
            }
            xDoc.Save("C:\\test.xml");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("C:\\test.xml");
        if (xDoc != null)
        {
            IEnumerable<XElement> xEle = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//property");
            if (xEle != null)
            {
                int iPass = 0;
                foreach (XElement xE in xEle)
                {
                    if (xE.Attribute("value") != null)
                    {
                        xE.Attribute("value").Value = "password" + iPass;
                        iPass++;
                    }
                }
                xDoc.Save("C:\\test.xml");
            }
        }
```

Comment: XPath is known to be slow in comparison to linq expressions in an XDocument.

Comment: I have answered twice if its correct Tick the answer to Accept instead of saying thanks ....

Comment: And use XDocument instead of XmlDocument ... it will easy to access ..and fast too...

Answer (score 1):

Other options is put this data in xml file and use the XML deserialize to read the data, which is very simple.

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MyAppSettings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <EXTERNAL_FILESERVER>/site/bugbase.adobe.com/files/</EXTERNAL_FILESERVER>
  <FTP_USER>password</FTP_USER>
  <FTP_SERVER>sjshare.corp.adobe.com</FTP_SERVER>
  <FTP_PASSWORD>password</FTP_PASSWORD>
  <FTP_READ_USER>password</FTP_READ_USER>
  <FTP_READ_PASS>password</FTP_READ_PASS>
  <WORKFLOW_NOTIFICATION_TEMPLATE>util/workflow_notification_template.html</WORKFLOW_NOTIFICATION_TEMPLATE>
</MyAppSettings>
```

AppSettings Class:

```
public class MyAppSettings
    { 
        public string EXTERNAL_FILESERVER { get; set; }
        public string FTP_USER { get; set; }
        public string FTP_SERVER { get; set; }
        public string FTP_PASSWORD { get; set; }
        public string FTP_READ_USER { get; set; }
        public string FTP_READ_PASS { get; set; }
        public string WORKFLOW_NOTIFICATION_TEMPLATE { get; set; }
    }
```

Read data from XML.

```
private static void ReadConfig()
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyAppSettings));
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("AppConfig.xml", FileMode.Open);
            MyAppSettings ConfigData = (MyAppSettings)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
            if (fileStream != null)
            {
                fileStream.Close();
            }
        }
```